# Accessing <li> tag, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to access a `<li>` tag in my first master page file. I tried FindControl(..) but it allways returns null.

Structure:

- First Master Page (which contains `<li id="element" runat="server"`>
- Second Master Page
- Default.aspx (need to access here)

What do I need to do to access the li element?

Comment: Are you able to access other controls using FindControl()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually access a server-side control like so:

```
Page.Master.FindControl("controlID");
```

However, if your tag is not set to `runat="server"`, you'll have to find it another way, such as getting the resulting Response.Content and changing it at some point.

**EDIT:** Since you're using nested master pages, you may need to go further back in the control hierarchy if you want to reach the "root" master and find a control in it.

Maybe: `Control li = Page.Master.Master.FindControl("controlID")`

Comment: here the code:
Control myControl1 = Page.Master.FindControl("element");

        if (myControl1 == null)
            Response.Write("errrr");

and yes it prints "errr"

Comment: Added another possible solution to take into account your nested Master pages situation.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten `runat=server`

Code would help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you don't have your master pages inheriting correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function which do find control recursively. SOmething like:

```
public control FIndControlEx(COntrolsCollection controls, string id)
{

   foreeach(Control ctrl in controls)
   {
      if (ctrl.id == id)
         return ctrl;
      var result = FindCOntrolEx(ctrl.Controls, id);
      if (result != null)
        return result;
   }
}
```